# Insert a nested Json into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, aws-documentdb

I want to move data from DocumentDb hosted on Amazon into MySQL table(**avoid duplicate insert so I am using 'INSERT IGNORE INTO**'). The data in the DocumentDb looks like:

```
   [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0e2c96eebd1c040a42523c"
    },
    "packNumber": 324,
    "DMMMeasuredCurrent": 1.75,
    "BMUReportedCurrent": 1.76,
    "error": 0.5,
    "operator": "Abc",
    "notes": "na",
    "reworks": [],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": 1594764438975
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": 1594764438975
    },
    "__v": 0
}, , {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f7b390701476b835e4379dd"
    },
    "packNumber": 420,
    "DMMMeasuredCurrent": 1.75,
    "BMUReportedCurrent": 1.74,
    "error": 0.5,
    "operator": "xyz",
    "notes": "l",
    "reworks": [],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": 1601911047462
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": 1601911047462
    },
    "__v": 0
}]
```

I created the Table in MySql as below:
create table auxcurrents1

```
(
BMUReportedCurrent varchar(50),
DMMMeasuredCurrent varchar(50),
notes   varchar(500),
packNumber  varchar(50),
__v varchar(50),
createdAt   varchar(50),
updatedAt   varchar(50),
operator    varchar(50),
idno    varchar(50),
reworks varchar(50)
)
```

How can I insert the data I am getting from DocumentDb to MySQL table? The following code, the snippet is what I have tried so far, but it didn't insert the data inside the MySQL table.

```
    import pymongo
    import sys
    from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
    from bson import json_util
    import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import connection
    #import MySQLdb
    import json
    from pandas.io import sql
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:passwrd@host:27017/?ssl=**=.pemFile
    print('DocumentDb connected')
    
    
    #Create MySQL Connection
    mysqlConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',database='db', user='user', password='passwrd',port=3306)
    mysqlCursor = mysqlConnection.cursor()
    print('MySQL Connection Established')
    
    
    #Specify the database to be used
    db = client.everestdocumentdb
    col=db.auxcurrents.find()
    print('The next line will print col')
    print(json_util.dumps(col))
    
    
    #Insert Into MySQL
    rows = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES(%s)")
    mysqlCursor.executemany(rows,test)
    mysqlConnection.commit()

    print('Ran the db.execute command')
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO table SET ?`

Comment: @aRvi how to use? Can you modify it as per my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more obvious problem here is you didn't set `test` anywhere before the row `mysqlCursor.executemany(rows, test)`

But the main point is to recall MySql is, unlike MongoDB, a relational database so you can't just insert a JSON on it. You can't do something like `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (myJson)` expecting that each JSON field will populate the correct column in the table.

To do what you want, first, you need to convert your JSON to a list of dictionaries and then convert it to a list of lists. Something like that:

```
import json

with open("a.json") as data:
    dictionary = json.load(myJsonString)

rows = []
for field in dictionary:
    rows.append((
        field["_id"]["$oid"],
        field["packNumber"],
        field["DMMMeasuredCurrent"],
        #...other columns
        field["__v"]
    ))

print(rows)
```

Now you can use

```
sql = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES(%s, %s, %s,...)")
mysqlCursor.executemany(sql,rows)
```

(Notice you need a `%s` for each column)

Besides that, you need to guarantee that the `field` order match with the columns order of database or (the better option IMO) explicitly declare the column names in the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table Col1, Col2, Col3,...,ColN VALUES (%s, %s, %s,...,%s)")
```

Finally, you may need to have to work the field `reworks` once you are converting a list to a String and also the date fields that may need an explicit conversion.

That is all. I hope I have helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I have now understood the logic based on your explanation. But it is giving an error:  field["_id"]["$oid"],
TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is not subscriptable.. Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: That means the object is not a container of objects like a list. You need to figure out what type of object `field` is, and if it is a list as expected, then see if field["_id"] is also a list. Did you used `json.load` ?

Comment: Yes, I used json.loads

Comment: My bad @Shrads. My example was incomplete. `json.load` expect a file stream, not a string. I fixed my answer to reflect that. You can use a string as well instead of a file, but in that case, you need to use 'json.loads' (with an "s" at the end).