# Automatically create table for complex json data in SQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json, automation

i have a complex JSON data which i have to store it in MySQL using python. i tried to do it manually by giving all the column names and it was working but only for one file. When i tried to do it for other file it was showing errors as the other file have few extra columns. Is it possible to create table automatically without me creating table and columns and when there is any value missing in a column,it should take it as null.

i have used this link to do manually create table  [Insert a nested Json into MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232669/insert-a-nested-json-into-mysql-table)

Comment: you have to program that so that it can fill all tables, there will be no automation

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand how unsafe such an automation is. But if you wish there are 2 options:

1. Scan entire set of json-s before table creation and build ‘complete’ data field tree, e.g. the following 2 json-s:
   {“a”: ..., “b”: ...}
   {“a”: ..., “c”: {“d”: ...}}
   sum up into the following set of ‘branches’:
   • a
   • b
   • c.d
   which mean the most common json for your dataset is
   {“a”: ..., “b”: ..., “c”: {“d”: ...}}
   (“...” are not matter as we talk about structure only)

So having set of branches you can translate it to set of column names, e.g. “c.d” -> “c__d”. And having that set it’s easy to generate CREATE TABLE-sql.

2. Another option is to collect ‘most common json’ (or field tree) on the fly and *dynamically* change table structure. You can create a table without columns at all at first (or with ID only or other unique column if SQL doesn’t allow empty column set). Then on each new field branch discovered in next json you generate and apply to your table an ALTER TABLE-sql with new column name formed in the same way is in previous alternative and that‘s all.